# Google Identity ToolKit Returning 403 Error

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication

```
POST http://localhost:9099/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=AIzaSyA-4RHHuZdnurs0OtlcgmBWkuIgda6Ru8k 400 (Bad Request)
```

I know there's a similar error to this on Stack and it mentioned to replace the API Endpoint URL (or the like with the one mentioned in the solution. I couldn't find where the URL was in my files for my Flutter project. Here's the supposed working URL:

```
http://localhost:[PORT]/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API-KEY]
```